# How to query for below Signup Button element in Cypress to click on it

Tags: cypress

How to query for below Signup Button element in Cypress to click on it. Signup form has a button of Sign UP below is the Angular code for that button.

```
cy.contains('Sign Up).click() >>><button _ngcontent-ixw-c248="" nz-button="" nzblock="" nzsize="large" nzshape="round" nztype="primary" ng-reflect-nz-block="" ng-reflect-nz-size="large" ng-reflect-nz-shape="round" ng-reflect-nz-type="primary" class="ng-tns-c88-13 ant-btn ant-btn-primary ant-btn-round ant-btn-lg ant-btn-block" ng-reflect-nz-loading="false"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><span class="ng-star-inserted"> Sign Up </span></button>
```

Comment: That should work - what error are you get?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Sign Up` is inside the span element, you could try below way to click on that button. Also the Sign Up has some space to the left and right of the text.

```
cy.get('button > span').contains(" Sign Up ").click({force:true});
```

If the `class` is not a dynamic one, you could also try by getting the class, as below .

```
cy.get('.ng-tns-c88-13 span').contains(" Sign Up ").click({force:true});
```

note: I am using `force:true` as I haven't seen the complete html page, if the button is wrapped under other html tags some time you need to pass `force:true` inside click, else it is not required, as below;

```
cy.get('button > span').contains(" Sign Up ").click();
```